# Composer assumes file in wrong directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony, composer-php

I want to install the pdf bundle to my symfony 2.1 system (https://packagist.org/packages/psliwa/pdf-bundle)
Since it requires some Zend libraries, composer will install them too, but will later not find the installed files:

Actual File Location:

```
vendors/zendframework/zend-sdtlib/Zend/Stdlib/compatibility/autoload.php
```

Assumed File Location:

```
vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/compatibility/autoload.php
```

That causes composer to fail (not only for the stdlib). Does someone have a idea or a suggestion what to do??
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a [recently-fixed bug](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendStdlib/commit/dad5cf28ec6ffbdbdd13990611d8f4407bf426a7) in the `composer.json` for the `zendframework/zend-stdlib` component.

I don't know how often packagist gets updated from the related GitHub repositories. Until that occurs, you could point your own component `composer.json` file to the github-hosted one using:

```
{
    "repositories" : [
        {
            "type" : "vcs",
            "url"  : "https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendStdlib.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "zendframework/Component_ZendStdlib" : "dev-master"
    }
}
```

**Update**

From [Packagist "About" page](https://packagist.org/about):

> Existing packages without auto-updating (GitHub hook) will be crawled once a day for updates. When the GitHub hook is enabled packages are crawled whenever you push, or at least once a week in case the crawl failed.

So, not sure why the update hasn't yet hit Packagist. Might want to submit something to the ZF folks asking about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, helped me out!! I'd give you a vote, if I had the necessary reputation with this account, my old one got broken...

Comment: Hmmm, only [takes 15 rep to vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Just sayin'... ;-)